# jQuery just ignore margin or margin-* using .css()?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I add margin or margin-* with jQuery, it just ignores it, but any other rule works fine.

```js
var children = *** 

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) 
{
    var item =$(children[i]);
    item.css({"margin-right" : '10px',"display":"block"});
}
```

the result would be like:

```
<div class="item" style="display: block;"></div>
```

Comment: You have a space between the property and the colon. Try removing it so its "margin-right": "10px"

Comment: It's working just fine for me. Are you sure it's not being applied and you just can't see the visual change? Can you see `margin-right` being applied in the inspector?

Comment: @jcruz I don't think the spacing is an issue

Comment: @AndyHoffman yes I've checked it on all popular browsers too, even wrapping it with another element using .wrap() doesn't work, just the padding and the other rules were added.

Comment: What does your full variable assignment look like? `var children = *** ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to emulate what you might have done in your `jQuery` snippet, but it is likely different since my example works.

```js
var children = $(".container > span");

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) 
{
    var item =$(children[i]);
    item.css({"margin-right" : '10px',"display":"block"});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span>Child one</span>
  <span>Child two</span>  
</div>
```

Comment: It turns out there are two functions conflicting with each other in my plugin the other one trying to manipulate the dom, and I call these functions inside "onresize" event to maintain responsiveness. I just reorder them and put the above code after manipulating the dom instead before it, and it works fine now. Thank you for your help

Comment: *even that I'm not touching any css rule in the other function

Comment: @Wael I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `children` variable is an array. I have tried something.
Please check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1H0S12BLCBC

If it's not something you asked then please try to create a sample in any online editor and post the link to better understand the problem.

Thanks

Comment: It turns out there are two functions conflicting with each other in my plugin the other one trying to manipulate the dom, and I call these functions inside "onresize" event  to maintain responsiveness.

I just reorder them and put the above code after manipulating the dom instead before it, and it works fine now.

Thank you for your help.